# broken pipe in nodejs CLI: terminal output is hidden

Tags: node.js, bash

When I run a little node program and I break the output through a pipe, the bash terminal output remains hidden and I'm forced to run `reset` (which works every time).  How should I restore correctly after a broken pipe to avoid going through `reset`?

The program:

```
const { unmarshall } = require("@aws-sdk/util-dynamodb");
const fs = require('fs');

(async () => {
    const input = fs.readFileSync(process.argv[2], 'utf-8');
    const records = JSON.parse(input);
    if (records.Items) {
        records.Items = records.Items.map((a) => unmarshall(a));
    }
    process.stdout.on('error', function( err ) {
        if (err.code === 'EPIPE') {
            process.exit(0);
        }
    });
    process.stdout.write(JSON.stringify(records, undefined, 2));
})();
```

And when I run this program like this and exit from `less` via a `q` keystroke, *subsequent* terminal output is hidden (after exiting the JS program and breaking the pipe).  Output is restored via `reset`:

```
node example.js dynamo_output.json | less

# no terminal output is visible
$ reset
# output is restored
```

Comment: Seeing a similar effect with `console.log()`. Noticed that changing the pipe from `| less` to `| cat /dev/stdin | less` avoids the terminal breakage. It's still driving me nuts. Have you found a solution?

Comment: One more thing I figured out: the problem only happens when you output _enough_ data; specifically, enough to cause `process.stdout.writableLength` to start increasing. So it has to do with process.stdout being non-blocking, e.g. discussed in this issue https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/11568. Why it's affecting `less` in this way, I don't know.

The shortest solution I found, is to pipe through `| cat | less`.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to work:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const writeStdoutSync = (str) => {
    fs.writeSync(process.stdout.fd, str);
}
```